# Simple Diet Advice?

Tags: diet, bodybuilding, body-fat, food, stronglifts

I am off work for 2 weeks soon. I am not doing much (saving money really!) so I would like to use this time to focus on the gym a bit more.

I have been doing Stronglifts with added cardio 3 times a week for 9 weeks now (Been lifting for a year prior to the program change), but I am sitting at 15.7% bf. I would like to lower this (ideal goal 12-13).

I want to use these two weeks to move closer to my goal (while hopefuly keeping strength!)

I am looking for a simple diet I can test out over these two weeks that combined with my workouts will hopefully reduce my bf% at the end. (Doesn't have to be that soon but I would like that).

I had originally thought about turkey, sweet potato, fish but I don't know how many times a day to eat?, what food will help towards my goals?, how much should I eat? etc etc.

Can anyone offer some advice? (I am open to mixing up my workouts to help too if anyone has advice that would help).

(Weight 73kg, bf 15.7%, height 171cm, age 21)

Comment: Just track your macros

Comment: Don't have experience in doing this, can you offer some advice? How can I find out what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some calculator to calculate your macros, a simple one like [this](http://macronutrientcalculator.com/)
There are three major macronutrients, or macros for short : Protein, Carbohydrates and fats. Using the macro calculator you can calculate how much of each do you need daily. Fill those needs, and you will lose weight, if that is what you want.

Use a site like [myfitnesspal](http://myfitnesspal.com) to track your macros. It is just calories in vs calories out. Let's say your maintance caloric need is 2500kcal. You simply reduce your intake by, lets say 200, and later 500. So instead of 2500kcal you eat 2000kcal. You have to simply try what works for you. Just an example tho. Use the calculator to find your needs. There are some more sophisticated calculators that require more information. You can find them easily when googeling "Caloric calculator" or "Macro calculator"

Losing weight is simple, if you track your macros. If you like the workout you do, keep doing it. From whatever you calculate your macros to be, i recommend consuming at least 1 g of protein for 1 pound of bodyweight.(If i remember right its 2g protein / 1kg of body weight) and build your other macro needs around this.

Keep eating clean. Get your vitamins from veggies etc. If you want to cheat build that day around the cheat meal you have chosen. For example, you want to eat a pizza. Find the pizza you want in myfitnesspal and add other foods around it, so you could still get your daily needs. Use some healthy fillers, like borccoli and spinach.

And also, don't forget your fats. Fats are important.

My calories come from 40% protein 40% carbs 20% fat. In grams it looks like this(for example) 200g of protein, 200g of carbs, 80g of fat.

THIS IS ONLY AN EXAMPLE.
This is what works for me. You are lighter than me so following those macros would not help you lose weight.

Comment: You keep saying "macros". For people that are new to nutrition, they do not know what "macro" is short for, or what those might be. Can you elaborate on your shorthand?

Comment: @JohnP good point, i added a broad explanation what macros are.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to find a source right now, but I remember reading that it's only possible to oxidize a certain amount of fat per day, when going over this limit, you will start burning protein (muscle) instead.

For a regular sized person, it's about 500kcal/day, fatter people can burn more of course. This means that you can burn about a kg of pure fat in two weeks. You'll then have 10.461kg of fat and a body weight of 72kg => 14.5% body fat.

What exactly that you eat doesn't matter very much, just make sure it's 500 kcal less than you use, and that protein intake is rather high.